# Android studio adds local absolute path to .iml file

Tags: gradle, android-studio

I have a project where on Gradle module depends on another. It seems Android Studio would automatically add some local absolute path derived entries into .iml file. They look like:

```
<orderEntry type="library" exported="" scope="TEST" name="_Users_jpu_git_workspace_lytroandroidcamera_blitzen_build_intermediates_classes_debug" level="project" />
<orderEntry type="library" exported="" scope="TEST" name="_Users_jpu_git_workspace_lytroandroidcamera_blitzen_build_intermediates_dependency_cache_debug" level="project" />
```

This is rather annoying as these line would replaced by something else when my coworker opens up the project on his machine. Can I avoid this?

Thanks.
Jia

Answer (score 0):

1st: you should not commit these IDE metadata into your versioning system. These are transient data.

2nd: if you really want to do it then you can play with `pathVarialbles` as described in http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/org.gradle.plugins.ide.idea.model.IdeaModule.html that is of course linked from user [guide documentation](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/idea_plugin.html)